# Dynamic Casting

Tags: apex

Is there a way to mimic dynamic casting in apex. From my understanding, dynamic casting is not available in Apex.

Are there any design patterns that can mimic 'Dynamic Casting'?

A user below listed that the following is acceptable.

```
String listType = 'Account';
List<SObject> sobjList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName('List<' + listType + '>').newInstance();
```

Can we do this:

```
String type = 'Date';
SObject sObjFieldType = (SObject)Type.forName(type).newInstance();
```

Answer (score 6):

The closest thing we have available to us at this time is the [Type class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm)

`Type.newInstance()` returns an `Object`, which still must be cast statically, but it still is enough to enable the type shenanigans required for, say, a factory method.

ex.

```
String listType = 'Account';
List<SObject> sobjList = (List<SObject>)Type.forName('List<' + listType + '>').newInstance();
```

or

```
Superclass subInstance = (Superclass)Type.forName('Subclass').newInstance();
subInstance.inheritedMethod();
subInstance.interfaceMethod();
```

Comment: I cannot find any documentation regarding .inheritedMethod() and .interfaceMethod().

Comment: @MatthewMetros those were just examples, not actual methods. The idea is that if `Superclass` has a method `x()`, and `Subclass` extends `Superclass`, you are able to call `subInstance.x()`. Similar thing for if `Superclass` is an `interface`, and `Subclass` implements that interface.

Comment: Is the following possible?

String type = 'Date';
SObject sObjFieldType = (SObject)Type.forName(type).newInstance();

Comment: `Date` is a primitive type, not an `SObject`, so no. This approach is really only useful for things that extend a class, implement an interface, are SObjects, or things like Lists or the "value" type of a Map (Sets and the "key" type of a Map can't really handle any type casting. Explaining why requires some decent knowledge of Type Theory and the Apex/Java type system, which is way beyond the scope here).